# Differential manchester encoding and data rate

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, serial, digital-communications, manchester-coding

I am trying to understand the specifications given by Transceiver chip (FT5000).

This chip encodes databits into 'differential manchester encoding'(DME) technique and send it over twisted pair.

The datarate is 78 kbps and clock frequency is 10 Mhz.

Does it mean the databit is sent every 12.80 us and converted into DME?

Below waveform representation is correct?

Kindly help me understand .

[image]

Comment: Can this help a little  http://www.ee.unb.ca/cgi-bin/tervo/encoding.pl?binary=0011&c=1&d=1 https://digilent.com/reference/test-and-measurement/guides/manchester-encoding

Answer (score 1):

Differential Manchester encoding produces only two output states; yours has three: -

[image]

Image from [wikipedia - Differential Manchester encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_Manchester_encoding). The top waveform called NRZ-L is regular serial data and, is the input reference waveform for the differential Manchester output waveform lower down.

- only two states appear on the output (high or low)
- consecutive 1-bit inputs result in alternate reversal of phase at the output.
- a digital 1 input results in a 1-0 sequence even when input data falls to zero
- the next occurrence of a digital 1 input results in a 0-1 sequence

Comment: In DME bit rate is half of the baud rate . In above  transceiver specs.  there is  no relation  between clock frequency (10Mhz)  and bit rate (78kbps)  . Will the internal clock of transceiver chip will adjust according to the 78kbps bit rate ?

Comment: @Ronnie I'm not sure what you are trying to say prior to asking that question and, to answer that question; it totally depends on the chip (I think you mean a receiver chip and not a transceiver chip)

Comment: if DME captures both data and signal information in it ,  then how 10Mhz of clock frequency is realized with 78kbps of bit rate ?

Comment: The gaps between your data will be regarded as binary zero and the DME will produce clock transitions in those gaps. It's then down to your receiver to interpret where the true data begins and ends. Maybe, if you cannot get that to work then DME is not what you want @Ronnie ?

Comment: Understood and clear !